# How can I update data in database by migration with slash?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, migration

I've problem by migrating.

This one is my code :

```
UPDATE table_name set table_field = '\\xyz\\xyz\\xyz\\xyz' where table_field like '\\\\zxy\\\\zxy\\\\zxy\\\\zxy'
```

It worked in mysql Workbench. but with cake php by migrating doesn't work. When I update another data in another field, It worked but with slash or another things I don't know, It doesn't work.

```
$index = $this->execute(" UPDATE table_name set table_field = '\\xyz\\xyz\\xyz\\xyz' where table_field like '\\\\zxy\\\\zxy\\\\zxy\\\\zxy'");
```

$index is always 0.

Somebody can Help me ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with this code:

```
$index = $this->execute('UPDATE table_name set `table_field` = \'\\\xyz\\\Lib\\\xyz\\\xyz\' where `table_field` = \'\\\zxy\\\zxy\\\zxy\\\zxy\'');
```